# Trigger compiled successfully but still not firing as desired

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger

Here is my simple PL/SQL code for demonstration purpose.

```
create table cust(cname varchar(10));
set SERVEROUTPUT ON;
create or replace trigger tgr
before insert on cust
for each row
enable
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Trigger hit on insert');
end;
/
insert into cust values('John');
```

OUTPUT:/

```
Table CUST created
Trigger TGR compiled
1 row inserted // *EXPECTING* Trigger hit on insert
```

Comment: `for each row
enable
begin` --> remove `enable` , this is syntactically wrong and cannot compile, just `for each row begin`. The keyword `enable` is not allowed here, please examine [create trigger syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm). Tip: when `create trigger` command doesn't show any errors this doesn't mean that the trigger has been compiled fine. Please use `show errors` command to see compilation errors.

Comment: Tried it out by removing enable ..Compiled fine but Still not working

Comment: Run `commit` and messagess shoud appear.

Comment: no not yet appearing. I've put commit after the trigger as it was not working I put commit after the insert statement. First one threw an error and the second one showing norhing

Comment: You cannot add commit inside a trigger.  What @krokodilko meant was to run a commit after you have completed your insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE** because when you insert data to your table, there is no prompt or screen which shows the execution of trigger. this applied same for procedures , functions , triggers.

**Don't** use **commit** inside a table. it will throw an exception. if you want to use commit then make the trigger **pragma autonomous_transaction** (i suggest not to use commit.it will automatically commit) .

Also make sure you don't modify the same table in the trigger. it will also throw and exception for mutating the data.

sample code

```
create table cust(cname varchar(10));
create table log(log varchar(10));
create or replace trigger tgr
before insert on cust
for each row
enable
begin
insert into log values('test');
end; 
/
```

Comment: That was life saving. Thank You So Much

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` inside a `trigger` to check if it was fired or not. Some of the IDEs like `SQL developer` might not output the message , even if you use `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`.

However it could work on `sqlplus` . When i tried,  it did display the message in sqlplus. So, it is not an issue with the database or your trigger.

```
SQL> insert into cust values('John');
Trigger hit on insert
```

And if you issue `commit` or `rollback` on the transaction, the messages might appear in `sql developer`.

I would suggest , it is better if you can create a log table and try to insert records into it rather than use `dbms_output`.

```
begin
INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE ( log_date,log_message) VALUES  (SYSDATE,'Trigger hit on insert');
end;
/
```

Comment: Saying :Trigger TGR compiled, check compiler log

Comment: Have you created the `LOG_TABLE ` ? . I just gave you an example.

Comment: I dont know how to create a log table as I'm a new comer.Please help me to figure it out or suggest any link of resource about "how to create log file"

Comment: Create table log_table (log_date date, log_message varchar2(100) );